# Android WebView: is there a way to get a javascript stack trace?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, stack

If you have javascript running in a WebView, is there a way for that javascript to get a string representation of the current stack for debugging purposes?

Comment: try implementing http://eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/

Comment: @AndyRay That is awesome. I approve.

Comment: Turns out it's not really necessary - just take the idea and strip it down to:  console.log("blah blah" + new Error("stack trace").stack).  Ugly, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

@AndyRay pointed me to eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace.  You can probably use that, but I just took the basic functionality there and now use:

```
console.log("blah blah" + new Error("stack trace").stack)
```

Also, at the bottom of my js files I now do:

```
//@ sourceURL=snarkloading.js
```

Where *snarkloading.js* is the name of the file (it can include slashes).  That makes it possible to get line numbers and file names from stack traces when the file is included via an eval.

Answer (score 0):

error.stack is not perfect when i use webpack, it show bundle.js backtrace, but i expect source backtrace

here is my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70346537/6011193), use "stacktrace-js" convert bundle backtrace to source backtrace, and then out to console