# how to use browser js parse sourcemap

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, source-maps

in android logcat, I expect android webview raise js err with typescript source, following is my sample code

testdraft.ts

```
window.onerror = (message, file, line, column, err) => {
    if (err !== undefined) {
        (window as any).mapStackTrace(err.stack, (mappedStack:any) => {
            console.log(mappedStack)
        })
    }
}

var m = () => {
    throw new Error("pr")
}
m()
```

testdraft.js.map

```
{"version":3,"file":"testdraft.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["testdraft.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":";AAAA,MAAM,CAAC,OAAO,GAAG,CAAC,OAAO,EAAE,IAAI,EAAE,IAAI,EAAE,MAAM,EAAE,GAAG,EAAE,EAAE;IAClD,IAAI,GAAG,KAAK,SAAS,EAAE;QAClB,MAAc,CAAC,aAAa,CAAC,GAAG,CAAC,KAAK,EAAE,CAAC,WAAe,EAAE,EAAE;YACzD,OAAO,CAAC,GAAG,CAAC,WAAW,CAAC,CAAA;QAC5B,CAAC,CAAC,CAAA;KACL;AACL,CAAC,CAAA;AAED,IAAI,CAAC,GAAG,GAAG,EAAE;IACT,MAAM,IAAI,KAAK,CAAC,IAAI,CAAC,CAAA;AACzB,CAAC,CAAA;AACD,CAAC,EAAE,CAAA"}
```

how to parse testdraft.js.map?

**I know chrome://inspect can debug android webview, but I expect android logcat also raise backtrace with typescript source for app production stage analysis**

Answer (score 0):

I find "stacktrace-js" can convert bundle stacktrace to source stacktrace(or you can make own source-map parser)

see following:

testdraft.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<!--<script src="../node_modules/sourcemapped-stacktrace/dist/sourcemapped-stacktrace.js"></script>-->
<script src="../node_modules/stacktrace-js/dist/stacktrace.js"></script>
<script src="./testdraft.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

testdraft.ts

```
window.onerror = (message, file, line, column, err) => {
    if (err !== undefined) {
        (window as any).StackTrace.fromError(err).then((err: any) => {
            console.log(err.join("\n"))
        }).catch(() => {

        })
    }
}

var m = () => {
    throw new Error("pr")
}

m()
```

**use tsc compile testdraft.ts to testdraft.js + testdraft.js.map and run testdraft.html**

so the android webview solution is, use webview in pageStated run js load stacktrace-js and following code:

```
window.onerror = (message, file, line, column, err) => {
    if (err !== undefined) {
        (window as any).StackTrace.fromError(err).then((err: any) => {
            console.log(err.join("\n"))
        }).catch(() => {

        })
    }
}
```

**or maybe better way**, don't use webview api run above code, use webpack prepend above code in bundle.js first